Apple Sign-In Not Returning Email or Name in Expo React Native App After Custom URL Update on Supabase
I'm using Expo's Apple Authentication for sign-in in my React Native app, following the guide here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/apple-authentication/
We've recently updated to a custom URL on Supabase, and after making necessary updates on Apple's side to reflect this change, I've encountered a couple of issues with the Apple login functionality:

Hidden Email Issue: When users opt to hide their email, I previously received a masked email like xxxxx@privaterelay.appleid.com. Now, the email field is returned empty, causing accounts to be created on Supabase without email addresses.

Visible Email Issue: When the user opts to show their email, the account creation works correctly, but the user's name is not returned.


This issue does not occur in our web version, only in the native app. Below is the authentication code I'm using:
const signInWithApple = async () => {
  try {
    const credential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
      requestedScopes: [
        AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
        AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
      ],
    });

    const appleIdentityToken = credential.identityToken;
    const firstName = credential.fullName?.givenName;
    const lastName = credential.fullName?.familyName;
    const metadata = {
      firstName: firstName ?? '',
      lastName: lastName ?? '',
    };

    setNameFromApple(metadata);

    if (!appleIdentityToken) {
      return { error: { message: 'Failed to obtain identity token' } };
    }

    // Use the identity token with Supabase
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken({
      provider: 'apple',
      token: appleIdentityToken,
    });

    if (error) {
      return { error };
    }

    if (data) {
      setSession(data.session);
      if (data.session) setUser(data?.session?.user);
      return { data };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};

I am aware that Apple Sign-In only sends user information during the first sign-in (or sign-up) process. Typically, it's expected that the application will store this initial data for future use. However, in my case, the expected user information (email and name) is not being returned even during the first sign-in attempt after the custom URL update. This is problematic as we cannot store and reuse data that we never receive.
The code worked perfectly before the URL update. Has anyone encountered similar issues or can suggest what might be causing these problems?
What I tried and what I was expecting:
After updating our custom URL and making the corresponding updates on Apple's side, I expected the Apple sign-in to continue functioning as it had previously. Specifically, when a user chose to hide their email, I expected to receive a relay email address, and when they chose to show their email, I expected both the email and name to be returned correctly.
What actually happened:
Despite the updates, the behavior of the Apple sign-in changed:
Hidden Email: Instead of receiving a relay email address, the email field is returned empty. This results in user accounts being created on Supabase without any email addresses, which is problematic for our user management.
Visible Email: The email is correctly returned and the account is properly created on Supabase, but the user's name is no longer returned, unlike before the URL update.
I have double-checked the configuration on Apple's developer site to ensure all details align with our new URL and reviewed our code to confirm that no other changes might be affecting the authentication flow.
